# Cordova Framework7 using CanvasJS to export Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, html-framework-7, canvasjs

I have and application **running Framework7** build **with Cordova** and I'm using **CanvasJS** to generate different Charts. However, upon using CanvasJS while is build under Cordova and enabling the export option for the user to download the Chart as PNG/JPG, when the button is clicked nothing happens, although everything works fine through the browser and the image is downloaded fine.

What can be the issue?

Thanks!

> I suspect I may need to extract the CanvasJS image manually
>
> ```
> var canvas = $("#chartContainer .canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0);
> var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
> ```
>
> and use something like *cordova-plugin-file-transfer* to send that
>   image dirrectly to the user phone, or there is a better way integrated
>   into CanvasJS ?

Comment: What have you tried, what errors are you getting? Is anything logged in the console?

Comment: I was thinking to try extracting the image URL and sending it through cordova-plugin-file-transfer directly into the user phone, although I was hoping to avoid the usage of addition plugins and permissions. For the console I'm not sure how I can check any console while I have the APP build and installed on the phone.

Comment: You can try [exportChart method](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/chart/export-chart/)

Comment: exportChart works the same way as pressing the button provided with CanvasJS for exporting the chart, does nothing, already tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution a while ago and decided to come back to my question and post it. Hopefully it will help someone with the same problem in the future.

So my solution is as follows:

```
// ... your Canvas logic ... use the code after chart.render(); //
// I've decided to remove the original Canvas drop-down button and replace it with a simple one
$(".canvasjs-chart-toolbar").html('<button class="button button-fill button-small" id="download_image">Download Image</button>');
// Hooking the newly replaced button with OnClick function
$('#download_image').click(function () {
    // Just adding a small alert showing the user the image is being downloaded
    dialog.alert('Please wait... <div class="preloader color-blue"></div>', "Downloading Image");
    // Collecting the image from the Canvas container
    var canvas = $("#chartContainer .canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var f_name = "dwn_chart.png"; // You can use any name you want

    var downloadFile = function () {
        var download = function(fileEntry, uri, readBinaryData) {
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();
            fileTransfer.download(
                uri, fileURL,
                function (entry) {
                    var onSaveImageSuccess = function() { dialog.close(); dialog.alert("File: " + f_name, "Download Success"); };                                    
                    var onSaveImageError = function(error) { dialog.close(); dialog.alert(error, "Download Error"); };
                    // Using Cordova ImageSaver to appropriately save the image to the user gallery
                    window.cordova.plugins.imagesaver.saveImageToGallery(entry.toURL(), onSaveImageSuccess, onSaveImageError);
                },
                function (error) {
                    dialog.close(); var error = String(error.source);
                    dialog.alert('<p style="color: #800000;">Download Error: <b>' + error + '</b></p>' +
                        '<p>Please refresh the Chart and try again, if the problem persists, contact support. Thank you.</p>');
                }, null, {}
            );
        };

        var onErrorLoadFs = function() { dialog.close(); dialog.alert("Error loading file.", "Download Error"); };
        var onErrorCreateFile = function() { dialog.close(); dialog.alert("Error creating file.", "Download Error"); };
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
            // Make sure you add the domain name to the Content-Security-Policy <meta> element.
            var url = rIP + "PPM/data/" + f_name; // Example: https://yourweb.com/path_to_file/file_name.png (f_name)
            // Parameters passed to getFile create a new file or return the file if it already exists.
            fs.root.getFile(f_name, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                download(fileEntry, url, true);
            }, onErrorCreateFile);
        }, onErrorLoadFs);
    };

    // Sending the image URI to my PHP file through AJAX located on the server so it can be saved
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: rIP + "PPM/save_chart.php", // Here you should use the address of your PHP file handling the save https://yourweb.com/your_save_php_file.php
        data: { 'URI': dataURL, 'Name': f_name }, // Sending the URI and the desired Name
        success: function () {
            downloadFile(); // When is done saving it the downloadFile() function is called
        }
    });
});
```

My PHP Save file:

```
<?php
    $Data = $_POST['URI'];
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];

    function SaveChartIMG($Data, $Name) {
        $imgData = str_replace(' ','+', $Data);
        $imgData =  substr($imgData,strpos($imgData,",")+1);
        $imgData = base64_decode($imgData);
        // Path where the image is going to be saved
        $filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/PPM/data/'.$Name;
        // Write $imgData into the image file
        $file = fopen($filePath, 'w');
        fwrite($file, $imgData);
        fclose($file);
    }

    SaveChartIMG($Data, $Name);
?>
```

I know my code may not be the best efficient way, so feel free to edit it and tweak it as you see fit. I hope it will help someone.

Cordova Plugins used:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="4.3.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="1.6.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-save-image"/>
```